# Is there a way to update the state of TabBarView if it has a child StreamBuilder whose state changes upon listening to a stream?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to create a UX that looks like WhatsApp Dashboard in Flutter. I created a Scaffold with an AppBar and put the TabBar in the bottomNavigationBar slot instead of the bottom slot of the AppBar. Each of the TabBarView children is a StreamBuilder that listens to particular stream. The problem is that whenever the stream emits a value the StreamBuilder rebuilds (checked via logging build function) but the UI doesn't update until I switch tabs and come back to the tab.

I have tried creating a stateful widget that hosts the StreamBuilder and instantiating that as a child of the TabBarView. I also tried adding a listener to the stream and calling setState there but it didn't work either.

I expect the page to update the UI whenever a chat message is received but it doesn't update until I switch tabs.

```
body: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: <Widget>[
              ChatListView(),
              ...

class ChatListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatListViewState createState() => _ChatListViewState();
}

class _ChatListViewState extends State<ChatListView>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  List<ListTile> itemList = <ListTile>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: chatsListBloc.chatList,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print("rebuilt");
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            chatsListBloc.fetchChatList();
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            if (snapshot.data.isEmpty) {
              return Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'You have not started any chat yet. To start a chat, click on the Start Chat icon.',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              List<ChatListItem> dataList = List<ChatListItem>.from(snapshot.data);
              itemList.clear();


              for (int i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++) {
                itemList.add(ListTile(
                    onTap: () {

                      }
                    },
                    title: Text(dataList[i].displayName),
                    subtitle: dataList[i].lastMessage,
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                      backgroundImage:MemoryImage(dataList[i].avatar),
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[

                          Icon(
                             Icons.account_circle,
                             size: 40,
                           ),
                          (dataList[i].type == ChatType.Incognito)
                              ? Icon(Icons.lock,
                                  color: Colors.blueGrey[700], size: 10)
                              : Container(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: StreamBuilder(
                      stream: Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1),
                              (computationCount) => computationCount)
                          .asBroadcastStream(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) => Text(timeLabel(
                          DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                              dataList[i].lastAccessed))),
                    )));
              }

              return ListView(
                children: itemList,
              );
            }
          }
        });
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => false;
}
```

Comment: Post your code so we can see what's going on :D

Comment: Updated my question. Please check it out.

Comment: Got it to work. Had to use ListView.builder instead of the ListView and a cache list of ListTiles. Thanks for your time. Hoping that this will help those who unfortunately encounter the same issue